# Sound source locator using multiple microphones — How to?

Tags: matlab

I need to create a sound source locator using three microphones. I plan to start off by connecting three microphones to my windows PC, and then taking input from them using matlab to monitor their individual microphone outputs in real-time. How do I go about this? Can I just take a usb hub and connect three usb-microphones to the hub. Will this work? Does the sound card put in any constraints here? If not usb microphones, how else can I go about this? Can I use regular microphones with a mixer or something of the like?

Comment: I think this may be off-topic because it's about audio recording hardware, not signal processing.

Comment: Any chance you can tell me where this question can be asked? I was directed here when I asked on another forum

Comment: The sound source localization part is signal processing, but the "connecting multiple microphones through a hub" is not.  That's more for superuser.com.  I wouldn't use USB microphones because they'll have separate clocks and their sample rates will drift relative to each other, unless they are synchronous to the USB frame rate.

Comment: Sound Design SE could be a way to go as well.